# The measurement independent of the LDPI,MDPI,HDPI

Tags: android

Can any one tell me whether is there any unit in android such that if I set the value of a margin/padding with a value,then that will be automatically adjusted in the other type of devices.

For example- If I set the margin/padding as 10dip based on HDPI then the alignment wont be OK in mdpi or ldpi with the same code.
I seached about this but couldnt find any solution.

Comment: dp of dip should do exactly that. If you say it is not ok, can you explain why?

Comment: Because if I specify in dip in one screen...the program wont adjust iteself in other screens.

Comment: So are you saying 10 dip is always 10 pixels, no matter the device resolution?

Comment: Nope I meant a unit that will act like that...Suppose the unit is "unknown" then the 10 unknown will have the same no. of pixels in all the devices.
ie, HDPI,MDPI,LDPI.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Screenshots maybe?

Comment: The ratio of the measure in that unit should be propotional to the screen resolution.

Comment: did u mean dp or dip in your first comment?

Comment: Yes, 'dp or dip', sorry.

Comment: It is just that dip/dp wonbt adjust themselves in HDPI,MDPI and LDPI.If you want a more detailed thinking let x dip be 10cm in the HDPI.Then correspondingly as per proportion let us suppose it should be 7cm in MDPI. But it will not be so..So if I specify a measurement in the dip/dp then the measurement for which I have specified doesn't fit the design provided.Hope you got some idea.

Comment: The whole point of dip is that it automatically scales in pixels. So that it is more or less constant in physical length. Why would your design need a shorter distance on a sharper screen?

Comment: Because the LDPI has a smaller screen than MDPI or HDPI.

Answer (score 1):

MDPI, LDPI, HDPI etc... Specifies the resolution (pixel density) of a device. It Has nothing to do with the physical size of the screen. You can have small phones with an XHDPI screen, and big tablets with LDPI and the other way around.

If you want to size items relative to the size of the device, you can raise the LayoutWeight of the widgets. The left over space on the screen is distributed over the widgets with nonzero weight.

Comment: Ok,I understood what you are telling...but what shall I do in case I want to specify the margin or padding in dip?

Answer (score -1):

First of all i suggest you to use 8dp as common padding/margin between your views it is standard and now as you said you need a measure that automatically resize the space you mentioned according to the screen size. right? they you should consider using small/normal/large/xlarge instead of ldpi/hdpi. for more information i suggest you go through this guidelines http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html